# Trouble with image gallery jquery

Tags: jquery, html, gallery, image-gallery

I am doing a simple image gallery with only 2 images so far. I want the text to change with the picture. Currently the buttons don't work and I'm not sure why.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var currPic = 0;
var pictures = ["sk8.jpg", "3dprntr.jpg"];
var text = ['x','y']
$("#next").click(function(){
    currPic++;
    $("#myImage").attr("src", pictures[currPic]);
    $("#desc").html(text[currPic]);
});
$("#prev").click(function(){
    currPic--;
    $("#myImage").attr("src", pictures[currPic]);
    $("#desc").html(text[currPic]);
})});
```

And the relevant html

```
<div id="gallery">
        <img src="sk8.jpg" border="0"/>
    </div>
    <div id="buttons">
        <input type="button" value="Previous" id="prev" />
        <input type="button" value="Next" id="next" />
    </div>
    <p id = "desc">text</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use same logic for `text` which you are using for `image`

Also fix couple of **issues**:

- `id` is missing on `image`
- `var currPic` should be `var currpic`, which you are using in your further code:

**Try This:**

```
Try out this code:
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var currpic = 0;
    var pictures = ["https://gaytravel-destinations.s3.amazonaws.com/32491/united-states-beaches-and-scenery__small.jpg", "http://www.carolinasusi.com.au/cmsvltl/img/8/5/a/596dbfe80598106527a80d1ddddf6/Le-Marche%2C-Blue-skies-and-Le-Marche-scenery.jpg"];
    var texts = ["new text", "other new text"];
    $("#next").click(function(){
        currpic++;
        $("#myImage").attr("src", pictures[currpic]);
        $("#desc").text(texts[currpic]);
    });
    $("#prev").click(function(){
        currpic--;
        $("#myImage").attr("src", pictures[currpic]);
        $("#desc").text(texts[currpic]);
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gallery">
    <img id="myImage" src="https://gaytravel-destinations.s3.amazonaws.com/32491/united-states-beaches-and-scenery__small.jpg" border="0"/>
</div>
<div id="buttons">
    <input type="button" value="Previous" id="prev" />
    <input type="button" value="Next" id="next" />
</div>
<p id = "desc">text</p>
```

Comment: While that does make the logic simpler, the buttons still don't work.

Comment: @KaitJardine Oh i got couple of issues in your js code, updated answer as well, Use answer now
Also you can run code snippet to check the demo,

Comment: No error, but I got the text to change but the pictures still don't. I'll update the original post with the new code

Comment: @KaitJardine image are not changing because you miss the `id` on `image` which you are using in JS, also check above example by running it.

Comment: Thanks! I've got it now.